# Apache serves some file types slowly... sometimes

Tags: apache-2.2

So just explaining this one is odd and I have no idea what information to provide. Essentially, apache serves up some file types extremely slowly compared to other files, but inconsistently. Generally the file types which go slowly are media files such as avi, mp4, mpg, etc. Transferring a large .txt file is no problem. I have no idea where to even begin looking for the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to the media files being non-compressible, whereas the text files are automatically compressed with `gzip` or `deflate` for supported clients, and thus appear to download faster.

It may also be related to your internet connection:  perhaps your internet connection, or some proxies around it, use some behind-the-scenes compression of your traffic, thus making it appear that text files are served faster.

Alternatively, if you're using some cool new filesystems with disc compression, this might also be related to the fact that the text files are compressed at the storage medium, and are faster to read into memory, whereas the media files are not compressed, and require intensive disc IO for reading.

Comment: So all of these things did cross my mind, but I don't believe it is any of them. When I monitor the data transfer rate, that is what is what changes. This rules out compression. 

As for the internet connection, I thought it may be rate limiting certain file types, but compressing the file, to mask it's actual file type, doesn't change the transfer speed.

Finally there is the file system stuff. It is just an ext4 disk. Nothing fancy. 

Also, these problems only appear sometimes. And I haven't seen any particular pattern yet.